# Automatically create new PR from specific branch using GitHub actions?

Tags: github-actions

I have 3 branches:

- `develop`
- `test`
- `master`

I want to setup an automated process to be triggered upon `test` branch getting updated i.e., it should automatically create PR to `master`

Let's say, I create a PR from `develop` to `test`, once the merge is completed manually. I want to setup a GitHub action to automatically create a new PR from `test` to `master`.

Is it possible to do this? Is there any marketplace GitHub action that meets my requirements? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with [create-pull-request](https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request). Specifically, [this example](https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request/blob/master/docs/examples.md#keep-a-branch-up-to-date-with-another) should help you.

In your case it will look something like this:

```
name: Create master promotion pull request
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - test
jobs:
  masterPromotion:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: master
      - name: Reset master branch
        run: |
          git fetch origin test:test
          git reset --hard test
      - name: Create Pull Request
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v3
        with:
          branch: master-promotion
```